# How to modify file name if the file exists in PHP?

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, replace

I have a file hosting website and everything works except one thing. I cannot upload two files with the same name. I want to be able to overright the name of a new file with a format like `file_2.ext` i believe this can be done with the `file_exists()` function but I am having trouble getting it to work. I will post the system I use to get files to upload below.

System:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_location, $location . $name)) {
    echo'<br>Upload was successful';
}
```

I tried doing:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_file']) &&!file_exists($name)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_location, $location . $name)
    echo'<br>Upload was successful';
} else if (isset($_POST['submit_file']) &&file_exists($name)) {
    !move_uploaded_file($tmp_location, $location . $name);
    echo 'File exists';
}
```

The method above did not post the error message.

Comment: Why not just create a unique filename every time? Something like taking the current filename, appending the current timestamp to it, and creating an MD5 hash of whatever that string is? That will generate unique filenames that are EXTREMELY unlikely to create two of the same.

Comment: `!move_uploaded_file()`? Huh?

Comment: I need the file name to stay the same because I use it to echo back to the user.

Comment: you can store the original and new one in a db

Comment: Why can't you return the unique filename back to the user?

Comment: They need to understand what file they uploaded.

Comment: So do you want to modify the filename, and if so which one - the one that was there or the new one? Otherwise, if you don't, what then?

Comment: I want to modify the filename from `file.ext` to something like `file2.ext` if the file already existed.

Comment: You're moving files to $location.$name but you're only checking if the file exists at $name.

Comment: Ok. And if `file2.ext` already exists you need to check for that too and so on. You're going to need a recursive function and it could get slow.

Comment: Good point. This is just a school project, so how would this be done?

Comment: Almost what Justin said, add a timestamp to the filename but don't md5 it (there's no point - if two files of the same name are uploaded at the same time, the md5s are just as equal to each other as the filenames)

Comment: OH... A TIMESTAMP! Fixes 2 issues at once.

Comment: Can you post that as a answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's really not worth it.

Comment: Timestamps are what I use, and sometimes even a pinch of `uniqid()` for extra flavour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. You will need to find a unique filename. You don't want to let it go indefinitely though, so add a limit to it.

```
function get_unique_filename($filename) {
  if (!file_exists($filename)) return $filename;
  $limit = 200;
  $path = dirname($filename).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $basename = basename($filename);
  $parts = explode('.', $basename);
  $ext = array_pop($parts);
  $base = implode('.', $parts);
  for ($i=2; $i<$limit+2; $i++)
    if (!file_exists($path.$base.'_'.$i.'.'.$ext))
      return $path.$base.'_'.$i.'.'.$ext;
  return false;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit_file'])) {
  $new_path = get_unique_filename($location.$name);
  if ($new_path && !move_uploaded_file($tmp_location, $new_path))
    echo 'Could not upload file.'
  else
    echo '<br/>Upload was successful';
}
```

Comment: It's a school project, don't teach him bad coding habits like that ;)

Comment: rofl. sorry didn't realize it was a school project :) the `uniqid()` idea has merit too. either way the idea is still the same. find a unique name. looping is a limited solution idea, agreed.

Comment: no probs, but generally you should avoid such pattern, think under high load how many people will have same filenames and how locked up your code will be when every single upload will end up in a loop counting 200 times then dying..

Comment: yep. like i said, not the best solution, but it works for low load environments just fine

Comment: It is a low load environment  so this is perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you're tackling it is wrong in my opinion , even if you need the user to have the "original" filename, you can't show them "file2.ext" if they uploaded "file.ext", that's just confusing and feels so wrong, take this example

Your server has files named `file.ext`, `file2.ext` and `file4.ext` and
your user uploads a file named `file.ext`, how would you handle that ? will you iterate over the pattern `file*.ext` and then add one to the biggest number ? or look for holes
and name it `file3.ext` ?, or will you append a random number to the file ? how will you handle collisions ? keep looping till it works ? it's just too much pain and might end up making your server really busy if you handle lots of uploads !

What I would do, is use [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid) for filenames on your filesystem, then have a DB that links original filenames to the UUIDs.

This way, all your users are able to upload an file named "file.ext", also it's cleaner to handle files since everything will be unique and their names will have the same length, and no need to worry about filenames in who knows what encoding, etc..

It'll also give you a bonus of being able to change UUIDs and show the same filenames to the user without worrying what they see, this way you're having a layer between the actual files on your FS and what the user perceives files.